# How to remove the loop. (Vectorization)

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

I am trying to remove the "for" loop from the following Matlab code. I know it is not necessary in this case, but I think that if I understand this case, in the future I will be able to apply the same concept to a more complex case in which it is really necessary.

```
clear all; close all; clc;

u = @(n) (n>=0)*1.0;  % Step Function
n = -5:25;
x_a = zeros(size(n));

for m = 0:10 % The loop I want to remove
    x_a = x_a + (((-1)^m)*u(-n+(2*m)))-(((-0.5)^(m+1))*(u(n-(2*m))));
end

figure(1); 
stem(n,x_a); 
grid;
xlabel('Sample Number'); 
ylabel('Amplitude x_a[n]');
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) `m` to a 3D matrix. Apply the same formula and get the results for each `m` in the 3D slices. Then [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) over the third dimension.

```
m = reshape(0:10,1,1,[]);   
x_a = sum((((-1).^m).*u(-n+(2.*m)))-(((-0.5).^(m+1)).*(u(n-(2.*m)))),3);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Can you explain why we have to use a 3D matrix instead of an array of 1D?

Comment: @JonAnderDíez There is no generalized way of vectorization. You just think of a way to arrange your data on which different functions are applicable to achieve the desired result. There can definitely be possibilities where you can use a 1D array. I just happen to think of a 3D matrix possibility